# Using multiple threads to work through a large List?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been assigned the task of converting a large list (4 million) of ids to usernames. For this purpose I've decided to delegate multiple tasks to my premium proxies.

```
public class ProxyWorker
{
    private static int _proxyCount;

    static void Run(List<long> largeList)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _proxyCount; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConvertOnProxy(i, largeList.Take(1000).ToList())));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }

    static void ConvertOnProxy(int proxyId, List<long> idsToConvert)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on the part of how would I delegate 1,000 to each task, removing them from the list after they've been select so another thread doesn't take them, and keeping the thread safety?

I understand that my current code just grabs 1,000 items without thinking another task is going to do the exact same thing?

Comment: The question is if Multithreading will even help you here? Multithreading will only help with CPU bound work. And a lot of multitasking is bound by anything but the CPU. List operations tend to be only Memory bound. Unless you ahve some relevant CPI work to do in "ConvertOnProxy", there will be no speed increase.

Comment: Why would u need to do that ? Just iterate multiple times with multiple `for` loop :)

Comment: I've using multiple threads to run in Parallel, and also avoid throttling from the same IP. That's my main purpose for doing multi threaded here.

Comment: Okay, network throttling and Protocoll overhead are one of the few cases where Mutlithreading can help in addition to CPU bound one.

Comment: ConvertOnProxy() should probably be async, returning a Task. Then, run it like this: `taskList.Add(ConvertOnProxy(i, largeList.Take(1000).ToList())`. There appears to be no need for actual threads here.

Comment: However, I would suggest not spinning up a huge number of tasks. Instead, spin up a fixed few (4 or 8 for example), and have them each pull from the list as needed. Convert the List to a Queue and it becomes pretty manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of where I would start:

```
static async Task Test()
{
    Queue<int> ids = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 100));
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoTheThings(ids));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static async Task DoTheThings(Queue<int> ids)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int id;

    for (;;)
    {
        lock (ids)
        {
            if (ids.Count == 0)
            {
                // All done.
                return;
            }

            id = ids.Dequeue();
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"Fetching ID {id}...");

        // Simulate variable network delay.
        await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(200) + 50);
    }
}
```